# VBA, Naming Cells

Tags: excel, vba, naming

Im currently trying to create a macro that will make my data analysis at work easier. Every time I run the macro I need to label over 80 cells with different names. I am new to VBA so I currently have 86 lines of code that all read "Worksheets(1).Cells(4,2), 1) = "Sample 1"" then "Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 3).Value = "Sample 2""...etc.

I was wondering if there is a way to write a more simple code in which i can only write the specific names in adjacent cells without needing to code so many lines. I need to figure this out because my macro is now to large and will not run.

I have tried using other codes like For Next statements in hope to streamline the macro but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Use a For Loop in example given. Something like:  For i  = 2 To 3 : Worksheets(1).Cells(4,i) = "Sample " & i. I am not sure what you were trying to reference with Worksheets(1).Cells(4,2), 1)

Comment: @QHarr though Sample 1 goes in `.Cells(4, 2)` so you'd have to adjust slightly: `For i = 1 To 86: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(4, i + 1).Value = "Sample " & i`

Comment: I should have subtracted 1 from i i.e.  Sample & i-1.  In my case. Well spotted though. My bad!

Comment: @QHarr that works too, nice.

Comment: I understand the For Loop, which is very helpful. But is there a way to write out 86 unique sample names to be entered into each cell?

Comment: Have all your names in an Array and iterate through it.

Comment: ^^ And use the position of the index in the array as an incrementor if required.

Comment: @QHarr can you give me a small example of how that would work?

Comment: @Colin if one of the answers is satisfactory, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to find a good algorithm for making the cell values (Sample 1, Sample 2, etc), and to make the cell coordinates. If your list is strictly down under each other with no gaps AND you can generate cell values then @QHarr's suggestion is fine. If you can't programatically generate the cell values then you can combine @QHarr suggestion with a predefined list of values like this:

```
Dim init As String
Dim c As Variant
Dim iRow As Long

init = "a,d,3,ww,12.5,cxz"  ' once you need to type in the values anyway
iRow = 3
For Each c In Split(init, ",")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = c
    iRow = iRow + 1
Next
```

If it is not solution, you can still "abbreviate" the lines using `With`:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .Cells(4,2).Value="Foo"
    .Cells(8,12).Value="Bar"
    .Cells(14,20).Value="January"
    ...
End With
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An example might be as follows. @AcsErno raises some good points about tailoring to your context. This is based on writing to different columns in the loop. You can swop to have the `i+1` in the row argument of cells if required.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim myNames(), i  As Long
    myNames = Array("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = LBound(myNames) To UBound(myNames)
            .Cells(4, i + 1) = myNames(i)
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```